# Windows 8 desktop app windows get stuck in front

Tags: windows-8, window, pinning

In Windows 8 while in the desktop, I will have programs get stuck in front. It has happened in multiple apps (Outlook 2013, Image Configuration Editor, Internet Explorer, (file)Explorer, Visual Studio). The window does not maintain focus, it just stays on top. Once  it happens, it will never stop until the app shutdown and restarted. I can minimize the window and that works correctly.

It has been happening since I loaded Windows 8 Pro (clean install DELL workstation).

Now that I listed the apps that I use the most, I'm wondering if it's happened in non-MS apps. I'll have to pay attention.

*Edit: Since I (@mawcso) am also having this problem, I'll add details:*

This occurs with various applications, including non-Microsoft applications like Google Chrome (shown in samples below).  At this point, I cannot remove the "pinned on-top" app without closing it. Re-opening the app, it returns to the "pinned on-top" state.

[image: GIF showing issue in action]

[YouTube Video showing issue in action](http://youtu.be/dPWuJWgKQa0)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are noticing this behavior in a wide variety of applications, this could be a bug with your specific hardware in Windows 8. Or, more likely, something is corrupted in your OS. You mentioned that you did a clean install on a Dell workstation - did you use a vanilla Microsoft Windows 8.1 or a crappy Dell bundleware version? If it is the latter, then that might be worth trying with a vanilla version. Another avenue to explore is graphics drivers - try out various versions and revisions to see if they make any difference.

Regardless of what the root cause is, there might be an easy workaround. [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a program that allows you to change a window's settings (and lots more). We can use it to set up a hotkey to deactivate a window's "frontmost" property. Then, whenever this bug occurs - bam, you quickly hit the hotkey, the window goes back to normal, and you move on with your life.

Sound good? Let's get started.

1) Download and install AutoHotkey from the official website (linked above).

2) Create a new text file called `AutomateStuff.ahk` and put the following text in it:

```
#z::
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, off, A
    SoundPlay, C:\Windows\Media\Windows Logoff Sound.wav
return
```

Explanation:

- The `#z::` part defines windows + z as a hotkey. (`#` is the AutoHotkey symbol for the windows modifier.)
- Everything between the first line and the `return` will be executed when you press the hotkey.
- `WinSet` is a command to set a window's property.
- `AlwaysOnTop` is the property that makes the window always show.
- `off` will make it so that this property is explicitly removed.
- `A` means that we will set this property to the activate window.
- The `SoundPlay` line will just play a sound so that we know the hotkey was successfully pressed. This line is unnecessary; remove it if you don't like the sound.

3) Save the file, then double click it. You should see the green AutoHotkey icon appear in the system tray - it looks like an “H”. Now, whenever you press <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it will fix the window.

For more information on AutoHotkey, check out:

- [The official documentation on hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
- [The official documentation on WinSet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I find this happens somewhat randomly but almost reproducibly if I use the Windows+d (show desktop) command to minimize everything and then again to unminimize everything. I am not sure if it is only triggered when I also have PuTTY open in Always on Top mode—maybe this issue only happens if you have a window which is Always on Top and the window manager mixes the bits around between applications incorrectly.

I don’t think it is an issue with your installation. I have had this happen to me on recent builds of Windows 10 too. It is one of the many reasons I avoid Show Desktop.

Like stated in [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/899016), this bit can be set on windows without them asking for it using things like AutoHotKey. This also explains why programs which have no support for setting AlwaysOnTop can end up in that state—they likely did not themselves ask for it and never had a GUI for you to set/unset it. So your only option is to use something like the AutoHotKey script or restart the program as you have discovered.