# Background application windows will not overlay foreground app windows when they recieve focus

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, window-focus

The symptoms are, that some (not all) desktop app windows will stay in the background, behind other windows, even though I have click on them, which would normally make that window receive focus and come to the foreground, above any other overlapping windows. I haven't found much rhyme or reason either. The two apps that exhibit this behavior the most, are Chrome and Visual Studio (the two apps I use more than any others, unfortunately). The other odd thing about it, is that sometimes, this isn't the case (like right now), and all windows behave as expected.

Factors:

- Windows 8.1
- Dell Precision Laptop (2 years old)
- 3 displays total, counting the laptop LCD
- Internal LCD and a Samsung LCD monitor connected to VGA port are controlled by an Intel HD Graphics 4000 card
- A Gateway monitor is connected to the HDMI port and controlled by an Nvidia Quadro K4000m Adaptor

I found one other question dealing with the same thing, but has received no answers, so I thought I'd ask to see if someone has a solution. This other question has an animated gif showing the behavior.
[The other question is here](https://superuser.com/questions/606968/windows-8-desktop-app-windows-get-stuck-in-front)

Any ideas out there? This is majorly frustrating. When this happens, I have to drag the window I want to see to another monitor, and sometimes, minimize other windows on that monitor.

*** EDIT - NEW INFO ***
After some deliberate investigation and research, I have determined that, at least for now, the problem seems to be specifically Visual Studio 2013. Apparently, when I go into debug mode (currently using the Azure Emulator, which may or may not have anything to do with it), I was able to replicate the behavior (only for the visual studio window, which may have been the problem all along, but I could have sworn that Chrome exhibited the same behavior). In this case, visual studio is in a "Stay on top" mode. So far, the only way I have found to clear it, is to exit VS and restart, which isn't a good solution. I haven't found a switch in VS to control that behavior, but it might be in there somewhere. If I find something, I will post the solution here.

Comment: Do you have any software that changes the behavior of Windows?  for instance one that makes the start menu appear into of the start screen?

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but it sounds like you're asking if I have some utility running that would, for instance, add a traditional Windows start popup menu, instead of the win8 start screen. if so, the answer would be no. I have no third party utilities to change the behavior of the shell, at all. See my edit for new info I discovered.

Comment: I've started seeing this behavior with 8.1 after Feb. 2015's patches. Everything from Outlook to Chrome to Remote Desktop Connection Manager will *sometimes*, but often, just appear stuck in the background. No amount of clicking on the background window will bring it to the foreground. I end up minimizing other windows in front of the "stuck" window in order to use it.

Comment: Not sure if this will work for you, but the top answer here (http://superuser.com/questions/269415/show-desktop-sometimes-sets-a-window-to-always-on-top) appears to have helped me.

Comment: @Richard, Unfortunately, no. Today, I have two Chrome windows open, as well as MS Word, all on the same monitor (of a multi  monitor setup). Here's the crazy part: one of the chrome windows will switch focus with Word, just fine, but the other stays behind the Word window (or the other Chrome window!). It's just crazy. I feel like this has to be a crazy display driver issue, or an OS issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that some application was set to *"Stay on top"* which causes it to remain in the foreground even after you've switched focus to another window (e.g. Playing a video in VLC Media Player with **Video → Always on Top** checked)

If you'd like certain windows to always remain on top, you could use [this tiny utility from Labnol.org built using AutoHotkey](http://img.labnol.org/di/always-on-top.zip). Run the program and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> whenever you want the currently focused window to always remain on top.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again to deactivate.

If you'd like to compile the [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script yourself, this one line of code is the source (uses [WinSet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm)):

```
^SPACE::  WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, , A
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Vinayak. I just added an edit to my post detailing some new info I found. I tried AutoHotkey years ago, but never really put any time into it, and failed to install it on my new machine. I may need to investigate it again. Whatever the problem is, it seems to be isolated to Visual Studio. Thanks, again.

Comment: @RichardB Does this script help with the problem? Are you able to de-activate "stay on top" mode?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, but I haven't installed AutoHotKey, and therefore haven't tried running the script. While it may be the only viable workaround, I'd rather not rely on a 3rd party program to change what should change with a simple focus. I did upvote your answer, but not marking it as the accepted answer, as it doesn't address the actual problem (i.e. is it a driver, OS, or other issue).